# why is my email validation not working

Tags: php, html, regex

I would appreciate some help validating an email address in PHP. The format for the email that I need is `firstname.lastname@mohawkcollege.TLD`, `.com`, `.ca`, or `.org` being valid TLDs.

My function is:

```
function validateEmail($email)
{
    $regex = "/[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+/";
    if (!preg_match($regex, $email))
    {
        return "<li>Email is in wrong format</li>"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Does your script run?  What have you tried?

Comment: You should escape the last hyphen in your first character class. That said, validating email addresses is notoriously difficult, especially with a RegExp. Use the PHP `filter_var()` function with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` set instead.

Comment: According to your question, your regex should be: http://regex101.com/r/zF1gI2/2 - please be clearer with your question, as I presume this is not correct...

Comment: the code runs but it accepts email formats that i do not want. I want the email to be firstna.lastname@mohawkcollege.domain .ca or .com or .org

Comment: @PedroIt - do you understand the regex you're currently using?  It clearly doesn't check for mohawkcollege, let alone those TLDs.  A quick search for a [PHP regex tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) like this one might help you.

Comment: You can't just randomly take code and hope it'll do your very specific use case without any work. Which part of that regex did you imagine would check for the `mohawkcollege` string? Your regex needs to be something like `/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@mohawkcollege\.(com|ca|org)/i`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, The reason I asked is that I know very little about regular expressions and had no idea how to accomplished this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+/
```

or

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]+/
```

Put - after _ would make a confusion, so either escape it or put it before _

Comment: ok that fixed the name and last name part but not the mohawkcollege that i need after the @ . I am new to php and I am very confused with regular expressions. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This doesn't address the question...

Comment: Do you mean you only validate mohawkcollege.TLD? Try [a-zA-Z0-9-_.+]+@mohawkcollege.[a-zA-Z]+